# Venues for short research articles

Tags: journals

I've just completed a short (5 page) paper on proving a certain combinatorial game NP-Complete. This is in no way a result of huge significance, yet it's one that I believe is publishable. What venues would be good for a paper like this? The only one I'm aware of is Information Processing Letters; are there other ones like this?

Comment: Theory of Computing has "short communications", but I am not sure how good of a fit your result is: http://theoryofcomputing.org/categories/short.html.

Comment: If the game is econ-related, perhaps as a letter in the [ACM SIGECOM Exchanges](http://www.sigecom.org/exchanges/)?

Comment: A less known journal where you could certainly publish it is http://www.acta.sapientia.ro/acta-info/informatica-main.htm

Comment: Post it to arXiv.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Fun with Algorithms](http://www.di.unipi.it/fun14/)!  Although it is a conference not a journal that you might looking for, among other things several NP-hardness results about (combinatorial) games are published here, including [this one](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-07890-8_4).

However this is a triennial conference (except for 2014, where the last conference was in 2012), so if you want to publish it soon then there might be a better choice.

Comment: I've seen fun with algorithms before, and it looks great! However I would like to try and publish this sooner, and also in general would like to know wahh other good venues there are for publishing short articles in complexity

Comment: Rahul, keep in mind that even though FUN's next deadline is probably half a year away, even a fast journal would take about this long. ECCC should be a good place to announce a complexity result: it's fast, provides more screening than arxiv, does not care about length, and does not preclude future publication.

Comment: @Sasho Nikolov I think I'm going to go ahead and do that. Thank you - I had always thought arxiv and ECCC were the same, but had never realized the difference.

Answer (score 6):

Put it on the arxiv. Yes, it is not refereed, but it does give you some limited visibility, and sooner or later, if it is interesting, it would get cited.

Answer (score 2):

[IPL (for Information Processing Letters)](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/information-processing-letters/) is a good place for publishing short papers.

Comment: Not really. Its published by the evil elsevier.